# Outlining a font with a shader and using distance field

Tags: fonts, libgdx, shader

I am using a BitmapFont generated by Hiero. I followed this great guide https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Distance-field-fonts to use correctly distance field.
I also use the shaders provided in the guide. Everything works great.

Near the end, it is mentioned in the guide that on top of the distance field antialias, it should be easy to add an outline to the font from the shaders provided. It has something to do with tweaking the **distance** parameter. I am sure it is easy for somebody who knows how to deal with shaders. But I don't.

Here is the frag code

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

const float smoothing = 1.0/16.0;

void main() {
    float distance = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord).a;
    float alpha = smoothstep(0.5 - smoothing, 0.5 + smoothing, distance);
    gl_FragColor = vec4(v_color.rgb, alpha);
}
```

And here is the vert code:

```
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;

attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;
attribute vec4 a_color;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main() {
    gl_Position = u_projTrans * a_position;
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord0;
    v_color = a_color;
}
```

From here how to add an outline with the shader?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The smoothstep function is basically a way to create a smooth ramp to antialias the edges of the letters. If you want to outline the letters, you need to shift the alpha antialiasing out from the letter by the thickness of your outline. So first you need a new constant for outline thickness:

```
const float outlineWidth = 3.0/16.0; //will need to be tweaked
const float outerEdgeCenter = 0.5 - outlineWidth; //for optimizing below calculation
```

and then modify your alpha so it it allows for the now bigger letters:

```
float alpha = smoothstep(outerEdgeCenter - smoothing, outerEdgeCenter + smoothing, distance);
```

Now you need a second antialiased edge to separate the opaque outline from the opaque letter. It's going to be the same as the old alpha calculation because it's in the same place.

```
float border = smoothstep(0.5 - smoothing, 0.5 + smoothing, distance);
```

Finally, you need to calculate your opaque color by blending between the outline color and the letter color.

```
uniform vec4 u_outlineColor; //declared before main()

gl_FragColor = vec4( mix(u_outlineColor.rgb, v_color.rgb, border), alpha );
```

So to summarize your new fragment shader:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform vec4 u_outlineColor;

varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

const float smoothing = 1.0/16.0;
const float outlineWidth = 3.0/16.0;
const float outerEdgeCenter = 0.5 - outlineWidth;

void main() {
    float distance = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord).a;
    float alpha = smoothstep(outerEdgeCenter - smoothing, outerEdgeCenter + smoothing, distance);
    float border = smoothstep(0.5 - smoothing, 0.5 + smoothing, distance);
    gl_FragColor = vec4( mix(u_outlineColor.rgb, v_color.rgb, border), alpha );
}
```

You can set the border color by calling this somewhere between `batch.begin()` and `batch.end()`:

```
shaderProgram.setUniformf("u_outlineColor", myOutlineColor);
```

Comment: Hi @Tenfour04. Thank you for your answer and my apologies for answering so late. It seems shaderProgram.setUniformf("u_outlineColor", myOutlineColor); uses a Vector2 for the value. Do the values correspond to (RGB, ALPHA)? How to choose pure red for example?

Comment: `setUniformf` has many different overloads, not just a Vector2. In this case we want to pass four floats, because we declared `u_outlineColor` as a `vec4`. You can pass in four floats like this: `setUniformf("u_outlineColor", 1f, 0f, 0f, 1f);` where the four numbers are the RGBA components of the color, normalized. Or you can pass in an instance of `com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color` which is what I intended `myOutlineColor` to be. So for red you would do `myOutlineColor.set(1,0,0,1); shaderProgram.setUniformf("u_outlineColor", myOutlineColor);`

Comment: The Color class is also versatile. You could do `myOutlineColor.set(0xff0000ff);` if that's what you're more familiar with.

Comment: (1,0,0,1) is the best ! Short and simple :) Thanks again

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is it possible to only stroke the outline, leave the inner space transparent?

Comment: Replace `float border =` with `alpha *=` and replace last line with `gl_FragColor = vec4(v_color.rgb, alpha * v_color.a);` Also remove the declaration of `u_outlineColor`. I think that should do it.